# How to rotate an SKShapeNode around its own axis?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to rotate an SKShapeNode around its axis (*a task I assumed would be easy to do in a framework like SpriteKit*). The shape rotates, but around an axis that seems to be off screen...

Any ideas on what's going wrong here?

```
import SpriteKit

class Square: NSObject {

    // this gets created and initialized later...
    var shape: SKShapeNode? = nil

    //… 

    func animateMe(){

        let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)
        self.shape.runAction(action, completion: { [unowned self] () -> Void in

            self.shape.removeFromParent()
        })   
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotation happens around the node's `position`. So rather than giving the shape node a path with an x/y offset to position your shape, you should **change the node's `position`**, and give it a `path` which is **centered around (0,0)** so that it draws the shape near its position (because the path is drawn relative to the `position` as well).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721352/why-skshapenode-does-not-have-anchor-point) as well.